# iphone dev How to find nspathstore2 memory leak from crash report?

Tags: iphone

i have got a crash report for my app from apple it talks about crash due to some nspathstore2 leak, now i am finding it difficult to find that error in the code after reading the report, here i the report

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31071f7e objc_msgSend + 22
1   Foundation                      0x35ba2210 -[NSPathStore2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:] + 84
2   Photobook                       0x000131d0 0x1000 + 74192
3   Photobook                       0x0001333c 0x1000 + 74556
4   Photobook                       0x000138a2 0x1000 + 75938
5   Photobook                       0x0001200c 0x1000 + 69644
6   Photobook                       0x000113ac 0x1000 + 66476
7   UIKit                           0x36fc30b6 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 142
8   CoreFoundation                  0x36ca51f4 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 36
9   QuartzCore                      0x36481a9e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
10  QuartzCore                      0x364816b6 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 210
11  QuartzCore                      0x3648583c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 220
12  QuartzCore                      0x36485578 CA::Transaction::commit() + 308
13  QuartzCore                      0x3647d4b2 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 50
14  CoreFoundation                  0x36d1ab14 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
15  CoreFoundation                  0x36d18d50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
16  CoreFoundation                  0x36d190aa __CFRunLoopRun + 754
17  CoreFoundation                  0x36c9c49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
18  CoreFoundation                  0x36c9c366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
19  GraphicsServices                0x30d7e432 GSEventRunModal + 130
20  UIKit                           0x36fede76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
21  Photobook                       0x0000229c 0x1000 + 4764
22  Photobook                       0x00002254 0x1000 + 4692
```

now i was assuming that this "1   Foundation                        0x35ba2210 -[NSPathStore2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:] + 84" suugests that the crash is at line 84 somewhere in the project, so i try to find this, but there is no  stringByAppendingPathComponent: used at line 84 any where in the project, so i am confused that how to find that leak in the project, can any one guide how to find this, thanx and regard.  Saad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

> -[NSPathStore2 length]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80cea00

When your application crashes with **NSPathStore2** notification whether its contain any method like above it contains "length" then go my solution below its work fine  for me i hope its also works for you.:)

**Solution:** The above error message means its have some problem with your "**PATH**" object variable.I explain it with you with an given example below:
Let us consider you have define the below code in your .m files any method where its need to define .Where "*dbpath*" is an **NSString** class variable that define in the .h file .Now you complete path is going to stored in "*dbpath*" variable as in below example descripted. Now when you are going use this "*dbpath*" variable in any other methods in .m file it then its get crash with the above message "*-[**NSPathStore2** length]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80cea00*" because you have not either "*alloc*" or "*retain*" the "*dbpath*". So solution of this problem is please either *alloc* or *retain* the "*dbpath*" variable in given example below. **THIS IS MY ANSWER WHEN I GOT THIS CRASH AND ITS WORK FOR ME WELL. ALL THE BEST TO YOU:)**
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    dbpath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydb.sqlite"];